# how create a sql query that creates the table without summation with previous value with csv file?

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I have a very large file csv. There are two fields: id and values (double).
Example of data file:

```
1 | 2.11
2 | 3.43
3 | 5.653
4 | 5.85
5 | 6.41
```

I want to get a mysql table:

```
1 | 2.11
2 | 1.32 (3.43 - 2.11)
3 | 2.223 (5.653 - 3.43)
4 | 0.197 (5.85 - 5.653)
5 | 0.56 (6.41 - 5.85)
```

As can be seen in the cvs file each subsequent value includes a previous.

how create a sql query that creates the table without summation with previous value with csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it while inserting to the table using the application level pretty easily. ALl you need to store the previous value in a variable and before inserting just take the difference with the current value.

If the data is already in the DB you can get the difference as

```
select 
id,
val,
@diff := if(@prev = 0,val,val-@prev) as diff,
@prev := val
from test, (select @prev :=0)r;
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28d03/2)**

Comment: How to do it when you insert?

Comment: I do not think you can do it in sql level while inserting from CSV, you need to handle it in the application level. If it needs to be in sql level then may be a `before insert` trigger to see the previous value and then set the value with the difference.